# angular material md-list not refreshing after update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

I implemented an md-list like so:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="file in index.files | orderBy:'type'" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ng-click="$parent.getContent(file, $event)">
        <img ng-src="{{file.face}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{file.name}}">
        <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
            <h3>{{ file.name }}</h3>
            <h4 ng-if="file.size > 0">{{ file.size }}</h4>
            <p>{{ file.mime }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" style="max-width: 300px;">
            <p>{{ file.lastmod }}</p>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

as you can see, the list will iterate through a container called files. It is defined in my index controller at the very beginning:

```
this.files = directoryService.getContent();
```

the called service "directoryService" provides the content of a directory and is implemented like this:

```
  app.factory('directoryService', function() {
    var content = [];

    return {
        path,
        getContent: function() {
            console.log("returning directory content");
            return content;
        },

        updateList: function(incfiles) {
            console.log("refreshing directory content");
            content.length = 0;
            Array.prototype.push.apply(content, incfiles);
        }
    };
});
```

after connecting to a webdav server the list shows all files in the root directory, which is working perfectly fine. After clicking on a directory in the list a method (getContent) calls the server again (http call) for the content of the clicked directory:

```
   $scope.getContent = (file, ev) => {
        console.log(file);
        if (file.type == "directory") {
            listDirectoryContent(currentPath + file.name);
        }
    };
```

the method listDirectoryContent() will call the server and update the directoryService.files object which is connected with the md-list:

```
 listDirectoryContent = (path) => {
        var lclfiles = [];

        var imagePathFolder = 'public/img/folder.svg';
        var imagePathFile = 'public/img/file.svg';
        var imagePathUp = 'public/img/back.svg';

        clientService.client
            .getDirectoryContents(path)
            .then(function(contents) {
                //Set default folders.
                lclfiles.push({
                    ...
                });
                contents.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (element.type == "file") {
                        lclfiles.push({
                            ...
                        });
                    } else {
                        lclfiles.push({
                            ...
                        });
                    }
                }, this);
                directoryService.updateList(lclfiles);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                alert(err);
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

});
```

so what basically happens is, that I wait until the http call is done by using .then(). After that I put the new content into the directoryService.files array by calling directoryService.updateList(newfiles).

So what happens next is, that the md-list is not updating its content UNTIL I click a random file... after clicking a file the list shows the content of .files correctly... It seems that the UI/list refresh is simply too late... do I miss something?

thanks guys.

Comment: Where is the `currentPath` set ?

Comment: there is a process which takes care about the path. I didn't paste it here since it is not relevant for the question. But I tested it and the path is always valid!

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky and met somebody who also had that issue. I don't know if this is a good approach! but it worked for me.
Inside my directoryService I surrounded the update method content with the following statement:

```
updateList: function(incfiles) {
            console.log("refreshing directory content");
            $q.when(true).then(() => {
                content.length = 0;
                Array.prototype.push.apply(content, incfiles);
                console.log(content);
            });

        }
```

The list is working now. After clicking a directory the new content shows as soon as the http call is done.

I hope this helps somebody.

Cheers